# Position of lighting current arrestor

Tags: surge-protection

[image]

Can i put lighting current arrestor before F1 in main distribution board?

Comment: Lighting or lightning?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what technology is being used for LPZ1, I would keep it as is shown.
F2 (usually thermal in close contact with the protection device) is there to prevent a fire if LPZ1 starts to cook off. But LPZ1 should also cause F1 to open if there is enough conduction at a power level high enough to open F1 but not create enough heat to open F2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but it will be much less effective than closer to the device to protect. It will protect much less from transiant current appearing after F1. Moreover F1 won't break if the surge arrestor is triggered, making the protection even less effective and causing higher dammage to the surge arrestor in case of lightning. A surge arrestor must be always placed as clos to the device to protect as possible.